# Open array files subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, subscript, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to open up a series of xlm files stored in an array, but the error keeps popping up that says that the subscript is out of range. Any advice? Thanks

```
 Dim AllFiles() As String
 Dim count, test, StartRow, LastRow, LastColumn As Long    
 test = count
 Do While (test >= 0)
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=AllFiles(test) 'subscript out of range
 test = test - 1
 Loop
```

Comment: Do count and AllFiles() have values?

Comment: Yes count contains the number of files stored in the Allfiles array. Allfiles() contain the file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't address the root cause (what ever that may be) but is a more natural way to loop an array

```
For test = UBound(AllFiles) to LBound(AllFiles) Step -1    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=AllFiles(test)
Loop
```

By the way, your dim statement `Dim count, test, StartRow, LastRow, LastColumn As Long` declares all items except `LastColumn` as `Variant`

Comment: Thanks @chris neilsen Now I'm trying to activate and use each of these files. But it still gives me a subscript out of range error in other places. whats the correct syntax:Windows("Allfiles(test).xlsm").Activate 'subscript out of range

Comment: I think you want `Application.Workbooks(Allfiles(test)).Activate`

Comment: With application.workbooks (Allfiles(test)).activate I'm still getting an error that says type mismatch error 13    
I simply need to bring the appropriate XML file that I had opened in sequence "to the front" so I can begin a copy and paste process how do I go about doing that?? Also what's the general syntax for an argument or index as part of a command line if that index contains a variable instead of just being a number.for example: lastrow = 10 // range("lastrow").select 'error

Comment: How about when you're trying to save a file as a brand new file with a name that includes that of the file names stored in an array: activeworkbooks.saveas "c:\allfiles(1):&:Allfiles (count).xlsm", fileformat:=52 'error I know this is a lot but I'm new to vba so any help is appreciated! Thks!